# とても、とってとても、超、めちゃ、めちゃくちゃ、物凄く、すごく、本当に、まじで differences in terms of degree and usages

Tags: word-choice

Pretty sure there are more(nothing formal because it's a major pain), but these are the only ones I can think of. What are the difference between these? The all mean "very". Degree wise, how would you rank them or are they all the same? Is there a word for the highest degree of "very" (casual)?

Addendum:
I get the feeling that some of them can be used for sarcasm (or only used for sarcasm). For example:

ものすごく: 俺あんぱん物凄く好き - literally" I really love red bean buns" but may feel like sarcasm. I.e: Implied meaning "I actually hate/ don't like red bean buns"

Or is whatever I said in the addendum really just jibberish rubbish?

Comment: 「とってとても」って？　---

Comment: これかな　https://hinative.com/ja/questions/4164763　。確か聞いたことありそう。詳しく分かんないけど

Comment: とって in それは私にとってとても嬉しいことだった is "for". It is それは私にとって、とても嬉しいことだった.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とても and すごく are general words which mean "very". You can use them in any situation. I think you want to say とっても、it is a casual way of saying とても. 物凄く is a word that emphasizes すごく. I don't think it is a sarcasm word.

In my opinion, I feel that 本当に and すごく are words for a higher degree of "very" than とても.

超、めちゃ、めちゃくちゃ、まじで are casual ways of saying "very", so you had better not use them in formal situations. めちゃ has been more used recently than 超 among young people.

Comment: Thanks. so in the list, the one with the highest degree of "very" is 物凄く or maybe 本当に？

Comment: Yes, but it's just my opinion. It is impossible to compare their degree because it depends on the person. I think めちゃくちゃ is also a word for a high degree of "very".